# How to use html/css in react/bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-5

How to use code of html/css in react/bootstrap?

Code in react js using bootstrap
How to use components and props?
It is showing errors even after installing bootstrap.

Can we use html/css code directly into react files into different folder..

how do we need to apply bootstrap to it.

please guide me through it.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers assume that you will be using CSS as your primary language for writing styles, which may not be what you want.

The reasons why you may not want to import a CSS file are:

- you may not want to have your app come with a huge stylesheet where the vast majority of the rules are not used.
- you may want to use a semantic approach when naming your HTML elements - that is naming them after what they are instead of how they look.

If you want to use SASS as your style writing language, don't import bootstrap CSS file into you component Typescript or JavaScript source.

Have each component come with and index.scss file, that `@use` bootstrap mixins, functions and variables to theme your component. And use a proper build toolchain capable of compiling those SASS files alongside the rest of the project.

There are many of them available. I'm myself maintaining one of them so if you are interested by a more thorough answer about that point, please comment and I'll update this answer.

You'll end up with more maintainable, readable and testable code, dramatically smaller stylesheets that only come with the rules that your app actually uses and way less bugs due to styling collisions.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to write steps down here:

**1. Create react app first using**

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
```

**2. Next install bootstrap in it not react-bootstrap**

```
npm install bootstrap
```

**3. Now import bootstrap CSS into your entry file so that index.js file**

```
 import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

**4. Now you can use bootstrap classes into your code as given here**

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, React with Bootstrap!</h1>
      <button className="btn btn-primary">Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**5. Now you can pass the data to by creating your components as shown below**

```
import React from 'react';

function MyComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{props.title}</h2>
      <p>{props.description}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent title="Component Title" description="This is a custom component." />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Along with bootstrap classes you can also use your custom CSS. You need to import your custom css files as you imported bootstrap css file.

Hopefully, this will help you. Feel free to ask questions.